# Netlify forms w/ GatsbyJS skipping one of the input fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, netlify

So, my form kinda working it is submitting email and message fields, but for some reason, it is skipping one of my input fields to be exact "Your name" field. I've even copied all code from GitHub of gatsby showing working netlify forms, here is the [link](https://github.com/sw-yx/gatsby-netlify-form-example-v2/blob/master/src/pages/contact.js)

And I don't know the reason and what should I do with it. I've read guide on netlify site, troubleshooting guides and nothing really helped.
Can somebody help?

And here is a code

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { navigate } from 'gatsby-link';

    function encode(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])).join('&');
    }
    const Contact = () => {

    const [ state, setState ] = React.useState({});

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = e.target;
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: encode({
                'form-name': form.getAttribute('name'),
                ...state
            })
        })
            .then(() => navigate(form.getAttribute('action')))
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <form
                name='contact'
                method='post'
                action='/contact/'
                data-netlify='true'
                data-netlify-honeypot='bot-field'
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                {/* The `form-name` hidden field is required to support form submissions without JavaScript */}
                <input type='hidden' name='form-name' value='contact' />
                <p hidden>
                    <label>
                        Don’t fill this out: <input name='bot-field' onChange={handleChange} />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        Your name:
                        <br />
                        <input type='text' name='name' onChange={handleChange} />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        Your email:
                        <br />
                        <input type='email' name='email' onChange={handleChange} />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>
                        Message:
                        <br />
                        <textarea name='message' onChange={handleChange} />
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
                </p>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    );
    };

    export default Contact;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are setting properly the `name` value, and the rest of the fields, on your state?

Comment: @FerranBuireu
Yes each of my input value has a name property, also I've tried doing this 
```code
const [ formState, setFormState ] = useState({
  name: '',
  email: '',
  message: ''
 });
```
Sorry, not sure how to properly include code in my comment

Comment: Add a `console.log` before the `fetch` function to see what's in the state

Comment: @FerranBuireu
`{name: "Test Name", email: "Test.email@gmail.com", message: "This is a test message"}`
So, console log outputs all data as supposed

Comment: Next step. Can you see in the browser's network tab if, in the post, all the data is being sent? As far as I understand, in Netlify's dashboard the `name` it's not appearing, isn't?

Comment: Yes, I see data being sent in the network tab with all fields, as well as state changing when I input values in the react components developer tools. 
Yes, In netlify dashboard only the name is not displaying.

Comment: Have you deployed your site?

Comment: Yes, it's deployed on netlify. here is the link https://vigorous-banach-5d4a61.netlify.app/
Styles are broken for now, so don't laugh :) Wanted all elements to be functional at first

Comment: @FerranBuireu Hey, maybe you have an update about this question?

Comment: If you can provide a CodeSandbox I may take a look to see if it's something in your code or in Netlify's side